# how to insert registration "datetime" and last login "datetime" in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have just completed the Blog tutorial in CakePHP documentation. It was easy and fun. But I'm confused on one thing. While creating a Blog in CakePHP I had two fields, "created" and "modified",  in my "posts" table.

CakePHP automatically did all updates there. I didn't write any code for it.

Now after completing that tutorial I want to make a simple registration form and also a Login page. Now my question is what field names do I have to use in my database so that CakePHP automatically update the "registration date and time" and "last login" for every user.

Oh, and also, if I have a "password" field in my table "users" then will CakePHP automatically hash my password before storing it in database? and if it do so then which hashing algorithm will be used? And if I have a separate "salt" field in table "users" then will it take care of it too, automatically?

Comment: You do realize that `"registration date and time"` === `created`, dont you? Don't make your life any harder.. For "last_login" just write that in the login() method before redirecting away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

created is filled "automagicly" on record creation so once a user submit a registration form you would save the data in users table with User model model :

```
$this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

Cakephp will set the created & modified to that moment, You can use created as a registration date. On the other hand modified will be updated each time a modification has been done to the user record.

If you want to keep the login date & maybe ip address etc., update them in the login function :

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) { 
            $this->updateLoginFields();
        }
    }
}


    protected function updateLoginFields(){
        $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->User->read();
        $this->User->data['User']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();
        $this->User->data['User']['logindate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->User->save($this->User->data, false);
    }
```

As for authentication i recommand you to read the authentication & acl tutorials in the documentation

Comment: If i am not wrong, I should have a method name as 
`protected function _updateLoginFields(){
     //code goes here
  }`
?

Comment: not necessarily if you'll update usersInfo in more than one place in your code it's a good practice to regroup the code in one place, you could've just updated the user's data inside the login method          if($this->Auth->login()){     /*read from db */         $this->User->data['User']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();      /* etc. then save in db*/   }

Answer (score 1):

Some additional advice based on Mohamed's answer. If your Users table implements TimestampBehavior (meaning it already has a "modified" or "last updated" field) then doing an insert as described will trigger an update to this field too. This would lead to redundant data in "modified" and "logindate" and it would obscure real updates to the Users row. In order to keep real updates distinct from login dates, use the dirty function on the model's modified field before saving.

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;

...

$user = $this->Users->get($id);
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, ['logindate' => Time::now()]);
$user->dirty('modified', true);
$this->Users->save($user);
```

See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html for more information on that.